# Different results between foreach and Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to iterate through a whole directory of files using Parallel.ForEach using the following code:

```
    List<string> _files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

    Parallel.ForEach(_files, (file) => { ReadFileIntoList(file); i++; });
```

_files contains 28015 entries but after executing, i is only 27944 and also the resulting list contains only 27944 entries.

But if I use the following code:

```
    List<string> _files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

    foreach (string file in _files)
    {
        ReadFileIntoList(file); 
        i++;
    }
```

i will also be 28015 and also the resulting list contains 28015 entries.

Can someone please explain or check where the error is?

Comment: `i++;` is not an atomic operation, so executing it in parallel will lead to race conditions. Use `Interlocked.Increment(ref i);` to fix this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't explain the difference in the resulting list. In ReadFileIntoList I add the properties of the file to a List<FileInfo>. So why are there still differences?

Comment: If `ReadFileIntoList(file);` is not thread-safe then you have the exact same issue as with `i++;` - a race condition. That depends on how the method is implemented

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. Using a

```
    SynchronizedCollection<FileInfo>
```

instead of an

```
    List<FileInfo>
```

did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have two race conditions, one on `i++` and one on whatever list it is that `ReadFileIntoList` reads into. For the first one, use [`Interlocked.Increment(ref i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netstandard-2.1). For the second one, use a [`ConcurrentBag<FileInfo>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netstandard-2.1) - since you don't care about the order of the files (you don't if you're using `Parallel.Foreach`) that will be the most performant collection.